# Why doesn't my Cordova iOS app start on iOS 15

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Our Cordova iOS app works fine on iOS 13, but it's stuck on splash screen on iOS 15 (probably on iOS 14 too). When we debug the view hierarchy, we can't even see a wkwebview instance. It's not created yet. What's the reason of this?

Here are the logs on XCode console:

> **2022-07-08 11:00:21.028611+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437902] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xc07f55ad aa617467 6e0bb79e c1a0d1c3 ... d5844058 fdbbc1ca }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x167f74be 8c26847b be1afbc4 d0f8127e ... 1d550b65 5d17b7d1 }}** **2022-07-08 11:00:21.030002+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437902] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xc07f55ad aa617467 6e0bb79e c1a0d1c3 ... d5844058 fdbbc1ca }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x167f74be 8c26847b be1afbc4 d0f8127e ... 1d550b65 5d17b7d1 }}** **2022-07-08 11:00:21.284540+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2436550] [Process] 0x7f965c020820 - [pageProxyID=13, webPageID=14, PID=47414] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102, isMainFrame=1** **2022-07-08 11:00:21.285884+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2436550] Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.424163+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437849] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}**

> **2022-07-08 11:00:50.424166+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2438537] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.425162+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2438537] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.425234+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437849] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.425827+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2438537] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.425854+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437849] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.428520+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2438599] ERROR: HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.431444+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2438599] Request <OSRequestRegisterUser: 0x6000008d7390> fail result error Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.432111+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2436550] ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal: Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.432257+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2436550] ERROR: Encountered error during email registration with OneSignal: (null)** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.436087+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437849] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}** **2022-07-08 11:00:50.436234+0300 Marketten SEÇ[47339:2437849] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}**

Comment: Are you using firebase ?